# What is the hbase.zookeeper.quorum in hbase-site.xml

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I would like to know how can I properly configure the hbase.zookeeper.quorum to point the zookeeper instance in a cluster mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hbase.zookeeper.quorum property is a comma-separated list of hosts on which ZooKeeper servers are running.

For example, "host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain.com".

Below is the example configuration in hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain.com</value>
</property>
```

If one of the ZooKeeper servers is down, HBase will use another from the list. As long as a majority of the ZooKeeper servers are up, the service will be available. Because Zookeeper requires a majority, it is best to use an odd number of machines. Typically 3 or 5.

For example, with four machines ZooKeeper can only handle the failure of a single machine; if two machines fail, the remaining two machines do not constitute a majority. However, with five machines ZooKeeper can handle the failure of two machines.

By default, the ZooKeeper service is bound to port 2181

Comment: Do all the nodes in cluster have the same value for this property?